# Overriding Spring bean

Tags: java, spring

I have the following scenario:

1. Spring project A with multiple bean configurations, including a bean named "searchHelper":
   `<bean name="searchHelper" class="com.test.SearchHelperImpl"/>`
   where *SearchHelperImpl* implements "SearchHelper" interface
2. Spring project B depends on A with a custom *SearchHelperBImpl*

What I was thinking of making is just copying the whole configuration into the new project and changing what needs to be changed, but that's not convenient and there must be an easier way of doing this.

My question is, how do I override the definition of the "searchHelper" bean to use *SearchHelperBImpl* instead of *SearchHelperImpl*? I want to use the same bean name in order for everything that uses this name to use the new implementation. I am using Spring 3.2.2

Thanks

Comment: Can you change the configuration of project A?

Comment: `<bean name="searchHelper" class="com.test.SearchHelperBImpl"/>` No?

Comment: @informatik01 yes, but where do I place that? Do I have to copy over all the beans from project A? or is it enough to define that bean alone in project B configuration? What I am trying to do is just use all the beans from project A and override only "searchHelper" as described above

Comment: @informatik01 can you answer the question with your comment about a separate XML file so that I can mark it?

Comment: @OmarK Sorry was away, I'll write a short post, no problem

Comment: @OmarK My answer is more related to how to **avoid duplicate** bean definitions. But the original question was about **overriding beans**, so the [answer by *nicholas.hauschild*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19779422/814702) is more accurate and relevant, and should be marked as *accepted*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NOTE

This answer relates to how to **avoid duplicate** bean definitions. For overriding see the [answer by nicholas.hauschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19779422/814702).*

---

More effective solution to avoid copying is to place all the beans that are common for both projects in a separate XML configuration file, say "common-beans.xml". And in the configuration XML file for the project B (and any other project that needs those beans) you **import** that file like this:

`<import resource="common-beans.xml" />`

---

### Simple example

*example-context.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd"
    
    <!-- 
         Assuming common-beans.xml is a Spring config file
         that contains the definitions you need to use
         in the current project. 
    -->
    <import resource="common-beans.xml" />
    
    <!-- Defining a bean with the implementaion you need -->
    <bean name="searchHelper" class="com.test.SearchHelperBImpl"/>
    
    <!-- Some other configurations if needed -->
    
</beans>
```

---

#### Useful reading:

- [Composing XML-based configuration
  metadata](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-xml-import)

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to utilize the `primary` xml attribute on your `bean` element.

```
<bean name="searchHelper" primary="true" class="com.test.SearchHelperBImpl"/>
```

Alternatively, if you are using JavaConfig, you can utilize the [`@Primary`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation.

```
@Primary
@Bean
public SearchHelper searchHelper() {
    return new SearchHelperBImpl();
}
```

Comment: This will not work for beans with the same method name in differnt configuration classes.

Answer (score 7):

One interesting "feature" (some consider it a bug) of Spring is that a bean with the same name declared later in configuration will override a bean declared earlier in configuration. So if your project B depends on A, and the configuration in A is included in B, and B defines a bean by the same name after the A configuration then the B instance will "win" and that's the instance you will get.

I would not recommend depending on this behavior, but would go with the answer regarding the Primary annotation. I just thought I would bring this up so you would be aware that even without the primary, or in case the one in project A is *also* primary you would know that the latest definition wins.

Comment: This is a good point. It turns out that even if the one from project A is NOT primary, it still wins. :(